# How do i assign the successive duplicate values of a string? PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, arraylist

How do i assign the successive duplicate values of  a string in a single offset of an array In PHP. For example `FFF2AA`

In array it should be

```
0=>FFF
1=>2
2=AA
```

In array format

Comment: is this a school project?  It sounds like a challenge you've been set.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/33196924/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This post [Count consecutive occurence of specific, identical characters in a string - PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26776170/count-consecutive-occurence-of-specific-identical-characters-in-a-string-php) gives you almost your perfect answer. you just have tu use '*' instead of '+' in the regex if you want to take into accounts 1 character strings (like the '2' above).

Comment: Can you better add that regex here with the modification for more clarity for the OP?

Comment: preg_match_all('/(.)\1*/',$str,$match);
$array = $match[0];